# Setting up CodeIgniter to show up on http://localhost/ci/

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, wamp

I downloaded and set-up CodeIgniter and Apache. I have started my Apache server, and in my config.php file in CodeIgniter, I set the base URL to:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/ci/";
```

However, when I go navigate to that URL (http://localhost/ci/ or http://localhost/ci/index.php), I get a standard 404 Object not found error.

Any idea what else I am missing? When I navigate to localhost, I see the WAMP home page. Not sure if there is anything else I need to set up.

Thanks!

Comment: is CodeIgniter located in the `ci` folder?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set [apache alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html).

For WAMP (i see this post is tagged as wamp) left click on wamp icon -> Apache -> Alias directories -> Add an alias.

Step-by-step screenshots [here](http://www.webdesign.org/web-programming/php/configure-a-virtual-directory-using-wamp.16605.html).